# Is it possible to execute queries in random order?

Tags: database-design, application-design, data-tier-application

I have a list of INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs queries.
My problem is that I always receive them in the wrong order (random), and I cannot know their original order.

Are there techniques to group/execute them in a particular order, so that I always end up with the roughly the same end-result as the source, no matter in which order I originally received them?

Comment: Seems like a very strange question. Race conditions would be the least of your worries. What about data that depends on each other?

Comment: @Phil That is what I mean

Comment: It is not clear what restrictions you are working under.  What does your input and target table(s) look like? Please edit your question to add examples.  Would a MERGE / UPSERT statement satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @MichaelGreen Just a flat table with two columns: INT ID and VARCHAR Value. And I need to insert new rows, and modify/delete existing ones.

Comment: You really need to get the statements in order, there's not going to be a dependable way to sort this out after the fact. And if you DO determine a way, it's not gonna scale or run with acceptable performance.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on the MERGE statement (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)? Would that work for you?  Which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

From your application layer, stamp each query with a timestamp and batch ID. Instead of executing the queries, store them in a temporary table with the format

```
sql_test | timestamp | batchID
```

When you know all queries from a batch have been received, kick off a stored proc that retrieves all queries from the batch, orders by timestamp asc and executes them

You'll probably want to add more logic about establishing dependencies between batches and how to deal with failed error,etc

Comment: They are coming from many different machines which are not under my control, so I cannot garantuee that the timestamp will be correct.

Comment: @Muis So, let me get this straight, you have queries coming from different machines, with out of sync clocks , and you need to figure out a way to get them in the correct order somehow?

Comment: Yes that is my challenge